# What are some best practices to ensure that my Google Chrome extension DOM logic doesn't break if the underlying markup changes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Google Chrome extension.

It will mutate the DOM of a website's page that I don't control.

Essentially, it will add a new input field in a form and intercept the form submission to store the added field in my own database.

To add the field at the right location I will use jQuery but I'm concerned that my logic will break if the owners of the website decide to change the markup / DOM.

How are people making their DOM mutating logic as robust as possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, you cant make it robust by just following some steps, as each page and html is unique.
however, you can at least have an alert system in your code such that it sends logs to your backend whenever it finds something wrong (unexpected sibling,  cant find an element, etc). then your backend can alert you so you fix it right away.
some sites might be migrating to a new version or doing A/B tests so you need to also take care or multiple site versions.

Also, investigate the ways to make an extension uptate deploy faster. you can can detect there is a new version and ask/force the user to restart.